# SSRS 2008, Force HTML3.2

Tags: ssrs-2008, html-rendering

I'm trying to export reports using the URL

In 2005, I could use `rs:Format=HTML3.2` and life was good

Now, with 2008, it appears all I have is *HTML4.0* but I **need** it in *HTML3.2* for a variety of reasons, the main one being, it is basic html and works in all our viewing devices.

Is there a way to get this *renderingExtension* enabled in 2008?

Or to trick the *HTML4.0* renderer into rendering *HTML3.2*, perhaps with an old UserAgent or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services Discontinued Functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144231.aspx):

> **HTML 3.2 Rendering Extension**
>
> The HTML 3.2 format in the HTML rendering extension is discontinued in this release. The rendering extension is no longer included in a Reporting Services installation.

Comment: It's nice their documentation is consistent.  "Format: Specifies the format in which to render a report. Common values include HTML3.2, HTML4.0, MHTML, IMAGE, EXCEL, WORD, CSV, PDF, XML, and NULL." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx But there is another page, which I can't find, which says that if HTML4.0 is not supported, it will fallback to 3.2