# C# WebClient, Only Support HTML3.2

Tags: c#, webclient

I need to call a webpage, but have my webclient act like it doesn't support HTML4.0, but only HTML3.2.

Is it possible to do this?  Perhaps with a different user-agent or some header I'm unaware of?

Thanks.

This is related to this problem:

[SSRS 2008, Force HTML3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662457/ssrs-2008-force-html3-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) implements **HTTP**. It contains **nothing related to HTML**.

If the website you're retrieving serves different content depending on the HTTP "User-Agent" header, you can set this header as follows:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.Headers.Add("user-agent",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
```

Which value you need to specify depends, of course, on the website.

Comment: @dtb, I know it doesn't know about the HTML it's retrieving, but I need it to act like it can't accept html4.0.  I'm calling a server that does some sort of sniffing and supposedly changes it's content based on what the browser supports.  So, I guess I need a user-agent that came from a browser that didn't support HTML4.0.  And IE6 isn't old enough

Comment: @dtb, I've tried going with the user-agent "Mozilla/1.22 (compatible; MSIE 2.0; Windows 3.1)" (actually several, that's just the oldest I've tried) and I'm still getting html4.0 content...  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Chad: How do you know that the website is actually serving HTML 3.2 content in some cases? Did you use an old web browser or is it pure speculation?

Comment: @dtb, it's SSRS, it's documentation says it will.

Comment: @Chad: "The HTML 3.2 format in the HTML rendering extension is discontinued in this release. The rendering extension is no longer included in a Reporting Services installation." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144231.aspx

Comment: @dtb, It's nice their documentation is consistent.  "Format: Specifies the format in which to render a report. Common values include HTML3.2, HTML4.0, MHTML, IMAGE, EXCEL, WORD, CSV, PDF, XML, and NULL." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx But there is another page, which I can't find, which says that if HTML4.0 is not supported, it will fallback to 3.2

Answer (score 1):

WebClient has no notion of what kind of HTML it is downloading. If the site you're accessing is doing some sort of sniffing, use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and set the [UserAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx) property to some really old browser.

You can set the User-Agent header using WebClient as well, but you have to [set the header directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) as there's no associated property.